# Software Development Life Cycle

Tags: software

I want to know why maintainability is important?

All I know is that software require updates and patches to either add new features or fix occuring bugs and errors.

But is there more to it than what I just said?

I also know that to make a maintainable software, there are certain things to follow and do. Such as good technical documentation and well written code which can be done by using proper naming conventions, comments where appropriate, spacing and indentation.

Are those the only ways to produce a maintainable software or is there something else?

Comment: *"All I know is that software require updates and patches to either add new features or fix occuring bugs and errors."* - combine this with the fact that there are probably millions of different programs in an uncountable numbers of machines, for all kind of things we can imagine - doesn't that give the need for keeping software maintainable some importance? I mean, if you are a munk living somewhere in the world without electricity, then this may not be very important for you. But the fact you seem to have internet access shows your life looks probably different.

Answer (score 2):

Here's why:

[image]

[xkcd.com - Is it worth the time?](https://xkcd.com/1205/)

The point of automation is to save time. Automate a task and save time each time it comes up. You have to weigh that against the time spent automating the task. That includes time spent maintaining the automation. To much and I'd rather just do it manually.

Comment: What does automation have to do with maintainability? What are you on about?

Comment: @SamiBasmadji time. The point is to save time. Everything a computer can do can be done manually with enough time. Saving time is the point of computers. When you write time consuming unmaintainable code you are defeating that purpose.  Makes as much sense as a self licking ice cream cone.